# Java wait until page load using Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

So i want to wait until page load using `Selenium`.

This is my implementation:

```
public static boolean isPageLoad(String url) {
    try {
        new WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(ExpectedConditions.urlToBe(url));
        return true;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

So do you think this should be enough or i need maybe to add another check for example search also the `body` tag ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just set the [pageLoadTimeout](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.Timeouts.html#pageLoadTimeout-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-) when initializing the `WebDriver`

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```